# Error message index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab

After looking at the other solutions with this error code, I have not been able to figure out the solution for this error. The variables are all cleared out in my command window so I don't have any interference from there. After inputting>> part2a(1.0,0.5,0.1,0.05) I get the error message. I assume as I keep going that the other parts are going to have the same problems.

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in part2a (line 12)
    y1(j+1)=y(j)+h1.*x;

```
function part2a(h1,h2,h3,h4)
t=0;
tf=10;
n1=(tf-t)/h1;
n2=(tf-t)/h2;
n3=(tf-t)/h3;
n4=(tf-t)/h4;
y=0;
x=(7.2*(sin(t))^2)-(0.208333*(1+y)^1.5);
for j=1:n1
    t(j+1)=t(j)+h1;
    y1(j+1)=y(j)+h1.*x;
end
for j=1:n2
    t(j+1)=t(j)+h2;
    y2(j+1)=y(j)+h2*x;
end
for j=1:n3
    t(j+1)=t(j)+h3;
    y3(j+1)=y(j)+h3*x;
end
for j=1:n4
    t(j+1)=t(j)+h4;
    y4(j+1)=y(j)+h4*x;
end
t1=0:h1:10;
t2=0:h2:10;
t3=0:h3:10;
t4=0:h4:10;
plot(t1,y1,t2,y2,t3,y3,t4,y4);
xlabel('Time in days');
ylabel('Change in depth of the tank in meters');
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `y=0;` does not change. Its a scalar, not vector. So when you execute y(2), you get error, as y(2) does not exist.

Based on your comments, to have y to store last value, one can do as follows, in the first loop:

```
for j=1:n1
    t(j+1)=t(j)+h1;
    y1(j+1)=y+h1.*x;
    y = y1(end);
end
```

Comment: How would you recommend I fix it? I tried changing y to zeros(n4) and I got an error message that says subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Comment: @B.Lott Depends what your program is doing and what `y` should represent. If you want to use 0 value for every `y`, then just change `y(j)` into `y`.

Comment: In this case, y=0 is the initial condition for the first iteration of Eulers method. I want every y after that to replace the one before it in the equation.

Comment: @B.Lott So just repleace y value with current one, e.g., for the first loop, add line at the end `y=y1(end);` and change `y(j)` to `y`, in previous line.

Comment: y=0;
    x=(7.2*(sin(t))^2)-(0.208333*(1+y)^1.5);
    for j=1:n1
        t(j+1)=t(j)+h1;
        d1(j+1)=y+h1*x;
        y=y1; end Is this what you were talking about? I get an error when run that says that y1 is not defined

Comment: @B.Lott I provided example for the first loop.